Vaadin 24 throws ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.nodes.Node
We have upgraded the project according to the "Upgrading from Vaadin 23" guide. The project can be built, but this happens when I try to run it:
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.VaadinAppShellInitializer.init(VaadinAppShellInitializer.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.nodes.Node
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)

First run vaadin:dance goal, after clean install

I tried mvn vaadin:dance, but I then got "No plugin found for prefix 'vaadin' in the current project and in the plugin groups".
Do I have to add something in the project for this to work? I found no information or tutorial how to do vaadin:dance. I only found this info
how to do this manually for an old V version:
https://mvysny.github.io/Vaadin-troubleshooting/
I did according to this, but it did not solve the issue.

Should I add vaadin-dance ?

with latest vaadin version run wvn com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:24.5.0:dance clean install

I could run com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:24.5.0:dance clean install, but it is still the same ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.nodes.Node when I run the project after that.

Are you using this library directly? Then add a dependency.

No, it is not used directly.

Please show your pom.xml

Use mvn dependency:tree to see where the dependency conflict is originated. Just noting here, that Vaadin does have dependency to Jsoup, you seem to have some other dependency to that too. So you need to resolve that by setting exclusion in your pom.xml.

Use mvn dependency:tree to see where the dependency conflict is originated. Just noting here, that Vaadin does have dependency to Jsoup, you seem to have some other dependency to that too. So you need to resolve that by setting exclusion in your pom.xml.
